# Spring boot - slow request/response

Tags: spring, jsp, tomcat, spring-boot

I am new with Spring boot (v1.4.1.RELEASE) but i noticed that the request/response in the embedded tomcat is very slow.. it takes 3-4 seconds to load 800k (jsp page) with very little sql requests. How can I optimize the request?

Comment: First you have to check what part is time consuming (on client and server). Is it network, request management, DB access, ...

Comment: This post helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62759292/12284870

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible answers of course, but I know about one Spring Boot issue that is directly related to JSP and the performance: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2825 (and the similar: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7039)

In other words, try to set this parameter in `application.yaml`:

```
server.jsp-servlet.init-parameters.development: false
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .. i will try this "hack" and will write a feadback.

Comment: @VasilPetrov did you try it? Did it help you? By the way I found another related issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7376 it's about enabling APR library for Tomcat.

Comment: Hi buddy, no ..II did not achieve success.. I switched it to thymeleaf 3 , and now everything is fine .. But i still love more JSP :)